# what is the seq counter after all master restart

Tags: seaweedfs

I just saw the implementation of compactmap,

Suppose that the SEQ I used is memory and IDX is memory. If all the masters are down at the same time, seq should start from 0. 
In this way, when I get the FID from the master, it will  be the same as before， Will this cause the previous file to be overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

No. The sequence number will be the maximum of all sequence number in all known volumes.

The (volumeId,sequence_number) pair is unique.